# Particle on a moving wedge: Reaction Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have been attempting to solve the following problem (my question is at the very bottom of this post)

[image]

And here is the answer for the first part

[image]

[image]

**Question:** Why is the reaction force $R$ not equal to $mg\sin \theta$? (I would think this is the case by Newton's Third Law, however, something is wrong with this logic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean to say $mg\cos\theta$ and not $\sin \theta$. See below (note I only display the force of gravity):

[image]

The way we usually get that $R=mg\cos\theta$ is by realizing that the forces perpendicular to the incline are balanced on the block. So we have $\Sigma F_\perp = R-mg\cos\theta=0\implies R=mg\cos\theta$.

However, this is only true when the wedge is **not** moving. Because the wedge is moving, $\Sigma F_\perp \neq 0$ so you can't conclude that $R=mg\cos\theta$.